# Должно ли доменное имя сайта всегда преобразовываться в один и тот же IP-адрес? Почему?

Tags: сеть, домен, адрес

Должно ли доменное имя сайта всегда преобразовываться в один и тот же IP-адрес? Почему да, почему нет?

Comment: Я знаю, что не должен преобразовывать в один и тот же адрес, но преподаватель требует более формального ответа.

Comment: Не всегда, IP адрес берётся из DNS-записи домена. А в этих записях может быть несколько IP. По такому принципу например работает распределение нагрузки, назвается round-robin.

Comment: Во первых для балансирования нагрузки на доменное имя может отвечать много серверов у которых разные ip. Во вторых при выходе из строя одного сервера запросы могут направляться на другой, сменой выдаваемого на имя ip адреса. Ну и еще найдется с десяток менее распространенных применений нескольких ip на домен

Comment: Формальный ответ. В стандарте, описывающем систему имён DNS, нет ограничения на количество адресов, которые указываются как соответствующие одному конкретному доменному имени. Это касается как A, так и AAAA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не всегда, IP адрес берётся из DNS-записи домена. А в этих записях может быть несколько IP. По такому принципу например работает распределение нагрузки, назвается round-robin.

`nslookup ru.stackoverflow.com` выдаёт следующее:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ru.stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   ru.stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
Name:   ru.stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   ru.stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
```

Или вот `dig google.com`

```
google.com.     90  IN  A   64.233.163.113
google.com.     90  IN  A   64.233.163.139
google.com.     90  IN  A   64.233.163.138
google.com.     90  IN  A   64.233.163.102
google.com.     90  IN  A   64.233.163.101
google.com.     90  IN  A   64.233.163.100
```

Как видите даже у этого домена далеко не один ip.

К тому же можно переопределить IP для домена например через файл `hosts`, который находится на локальной машине и имеет больший приоритет перед обращением к DNS.